# Validate that all of the checkboxes are checked in ionic

Tags: angularjs, validation, checkbox, ionic-framework

I have a form with list of checkboxes, as shown here:

```js
$scope.deviceList = [
  { text: "Dev 0", checked: false },
  { text: "Dev 1", checked: false },
  { text: "Dev 2", checked: false },
  { text: "Dev 3", checked: false },
  { text: "Dev 4", checked: false }
];
```

```html
<form>
    <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-balanced"
                  ng-repeat="item in deviceList"
                  ng-model="item.checked"
                  ng-required="true">
      {{ item.text }}
    </ion-checkbox>
</form>
```

Of course that I have more elements. but just for this case I show the relavent code.

Now, I would like to have a validation that the form cannot be sent until all checkboxes are checked.
Any suggestions of an elegant solution for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a function with something like the following would do the trick:

```js
$scope.validate = function(){
  var numChecked = $filter($scope.deviceList, function(device) {
    return device.checked
  }).length;
  return $scope.deviceList.length == numChecked;
}
```

And don't forget to inject $filter service in your controller or it won't work

Comment: Thanks eylen, where should I cal the validate() function?

Comment: You could call it in a button with ngClick='validate()' and if it's true then send the submit or you can play with the ngSubmit directive of the form.